# Export data in a xml using txt file in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

i want to insert a table in xml using

```
select * from Student for xml auto
```

But i want to do it in such a way so in xml there create the following line

```
 <Files> <File FileName="Student.txt" NumberOfRows="44" /> </Files>
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Write your query like this will give you expected output.

```
select( '<Files>' + 
(select 'Student.txt' as FileName,count(*) as NumberofRows from Student for xml auto) + '</Files>')
```